# This Batch File only half runs anyone?

Tags: batch-file

I want it to open note pad, place a quote, while leaveing note pad open a few then close notepad then shut down the computer.

```
@echo off
cd %windir%\system32
Start "" /b notepad.exe
rem 
"Everything fades so quickly, turns to legend, and soon oblivion covers it" 
-Marus Aurelius.
timeout /t 10 /nobreak >nul
taskkill /IM notepad.exe /F
turn_off.bat.
```

Sorry i know it prob a simple mistake but it got me stumped. word opens but i get no text and no shut down.

Comment: You don't need to open Notepad to create a text file. Batch files can natively read and write text files. It is very simple. `echo Hello World >filename.txt`

Comment: Thanks a ton for the advice, but it needs to be longer and i kind of wanted to know what i did wrong here. Not just write an easier batch file.

Comment: Batch files cannot interact with graphical user interfaces. If you need to do that you need to use a different scripting language like Vbscript.

Comment: You can write as many lines to the text file as you want. I was just giving you the basic syntax.

Comment: ok thanks see that what i was wonder.. thanks for your time sir

Comment: It sucks cause all my exp is in networking and I could make a batch file to ping a ton of different stuff, but the computer lab is not networked:(

Comment: All network people should know scripting. It was required learning when I was in school for Network Administration. We had to learn bash on Linux and batch files on Windows.

Comment: Well I said I knew networking not that i worked or was net+, but clearly you have shown my low intelligence. Thank you for pointing it out to me.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot interact with Notepad directly, but you can output to a temporary file and open and close it before deleting it.

```bat
@(Echo Everything fades so quickly, turns to legend, and soon oblivion covers it&Echo -Marus Aurelius)>"%TEMP%\_.tmp"&&Start Notepad "%TEMP%\_.tmp"&&Timeout 10 /NoBreak>Nul&&TaskKill /F /Im notepad.exe>Nul&&Del "%TEMP%\_.tmp"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got an A on the assignment.

Comment: @jamesbaker, please mark my answer as accepted, by clicking on the large check mark to its adjacent left.